# About sum of segments with vertices on the unit square

Tags: combinatorics

> Given $120$ points $P_1,P_2,\ldots P_{120}$ on the unit square, find $t\in\mathbb R$ for which there always exists another point $P$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{120}|PP_i|=t$.

The correct answer is $30(1+\sqrt5)$, but mine is $30(1+\sqrt2)$. And also I haven’t proved the uniqueness of $t$. My solution is:

- Proposition $\spadesuit$: There exists some midpoint $T_1$ of one of the square’s side with $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{120}|T_1P_i|\ge1+\sqrt2$.
- Proposition $\clubsuit$: There exists some vertex $T_2$ of the square with $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{120}|T_2P_i|\ge1+\sqrt2$.

For $\spadesuit$, let the midpoints be $M_{1,2,3,4}$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^{120}|M_iP_j|=\sum_{j=1}^{120}\sum_{i=1}^4|M_iP_j|\ge120(1+\sqrt2).$$ With the principle of averages, $\dfrac{120(1+\sqrt2)}4=30(1+\sqrt2).$ The “$=$” can be reached if and only if each of $P_k$ is on one of the $M_k$. Done.

For $\clubsuit$, let the vertices be $V_{1,2,3,4}$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^{120}|V_iP_j|=\sum_{j=1}^{120}\sum_{i=1}^4|V_iP_j|\ge120(1+\sqrt2).$$ With the principle of averages, $\dfrac{120(1+\sqrt2)}4=30(1+\sqrt2).$ The “$=$” can be reached if and only if each of $P_k$ is on one of the $V_k$. Done.

[For the above proves, it is a kind of typical max/min problem shown here.](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/133320644)

According to the Intermediate Value Thm we see the existence of such $V$ on the path from $T_1$ to $T_2$ going by the square’s outline.

I suppose we need to use the Intermediate Value Thm otherwise finding $V$ is hopeless, and $\sqrt5=\sqrt{1^2+2^2}$ possibly.